# How to insert xml data into existing xml in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i added xml file in my windows application, i want to add values to that from textbox.. 
i used the following code,

```
string path = "codedata.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            //Create neccessary nodes
            XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
            XmlComment comment = doc.CreateComment("This is an XML Generated File");
            doc.AppendChild(declaration);
            doc.AppendChild(comment);
        }
        else //If there is already a file
        {
            //    //Load the XML File
            doc.Load(path);
        }

        //Get the root element
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlElement Subroot = doc.CreateElement("data");
        XmlElement Companycode = doc.CreateElement("Companycode");
        XmlElement Productcode = doc.CreateElement("Productcode");
        XmlElement Productname = doc.CreateElement("Productname");
        XmlElement Brandcode = doc.CreateElement("Brandcode");
        XmlElement Brandname = doc.CreateElement("Brandname");

        Companycode.InnerText = txt_companycode.Text;
        Productcode.InnerText = txt_productcode.Text;
        Productname.InnerText = txt_productname.Text;
        Brandcode.InnerText = txt_brandcode.Text;
        Brandname.InnerText = txt_brandname.Text;

        Subroot.AppendChild(Companycode);
        Subroot.AppendChild(Productcode);
        Subroot.AppendChild(Productname);
        Subroot.AppendChild(Brandcode);
        Subroot.AppendChild(Brandname);
        root.AppendChild(Subroot);
        doc.AppendChild(root);


        //Save the document
        doc.Save(path);


        //Show confirmation message
        MessageBox.Show("Details  added Successfully");
```

it showing error near  root.AppendChild(Subroot); can any one help me, wer i made mistake.

Comment: object reference not set to an instance...

Comment: LINQ to XML is really nice in such a situation :)

You get this error because there is no instance of `Subroot` try add this line : `Subroot sub = new Subroot();` before this line`Subroot.AppendChild(Companycode);
` and change all `Subroot` to `sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root` is null. Try to add Root element when you create XML file.

```
 if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            //Create neccessary nodes
            XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
            XmlComment comment = doc.CreateComment("This is an XML Generated File");
            doc.AppendChild(declaration);
            doc.AppendChild(comment);
            doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Root"));
        }
```

Or use LINQ-XML

```
string _file=@"c:\sample.xml";
XDocument doc;

if (!File.Exists(_file))
{
    doc = new XDocument();
    doc.Add(new XElement("Root"));
}
else
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(_file);
}

doc.Root.Add(
      new XElement("data",
                   new XElement("CompanyCode","C101"),
                   new XElement("ProductCode","P101")
            ) 
      );
doc.Save(_file);
```

Comment: hi, i used, it returns saved, but no data in xml file

Comment: You either have set physical path `c:\file.xml` or have a look at `Debug/Bin` folder if your app is winform or console.

Comment: hai, when i test using break point, it shows the xml file with data i saved.but if i see in codedata.xml,its empty. Where it is saving?

Comment: Try to set absolute path and see what happen?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq to XML, here is an example :

```
var xDoc = XElement.Load("FilePath");
if (xDoc == null)
   return;

var myNewElement = new XElement("ElementName"
   new XAttribute("AttributeName", value1),
   new XAttribute("AttributeName", value2)
   //And so on ...
);
xDoc.Add(myNewElement);
xDoc.Save("FilePath");
```

Answer (score 0):

In null XML `DocumentElement` is `null`. Try add `Subroot` to Document:

```
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
```

root.AppendChild(Subroot);
doc.AppendChild(root);

```
// new code
doc.AppendChild(Subroot);
```

Comment: i tried ur idea, its shows the msg saved, but in xml file...no data is there empty only with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> i added my xml file by add new item

Comment: @chitra: I tested my code and its works correctly. check output xml.

Comment: should i add any element in xml, before saved btn